# jQuery.Deferred exception in jvectormap

Tags: javascript, html, jvectormap

I'm making a map with `jvectormap`. The map should read marks of a json file. However, when I upload the `html` to my site, the map is not loaded, only the container of this and when I resize of the browser window, the map with the marks appears.

When I click on inspect item, the following warning appears:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Can not read property '0' of undefined TypeError: Can not read property '0' of undefined
```

And the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property '0' of undefined
```

The error disappears and the map looks correctly if I directly load the marks in the script, but I need to use the json file. The map is available [here](http://cybertodo.mx/Mapa/Mexico.html)

The code of my html file:

```
<html> 
<head>  
<title>Franquicias</title>
<script src="./jquery-3.2.1.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script src="./jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="./jvectormap.mexico.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src = "./markers.json"> </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="mex-map" style="width:200vh; height:100vh;">
</div>
<script>
$(function mapa(){
$('#mex-map').vectorMap({
map: 'Mexico',
backgroundColor: '#b3d1ff',
series: {
    regions: [{
            values: {"c0": "1", "c1": "2"},
            scale: ['#d9d4ca', '#b3d1ff'],
            normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
        }]
},
markerStyle: {
  initial: {
    fill: '#F8E23B',
    stroke: '#383f47',
      r: 7

  }},
       markers: cdata
});
});
</script>
```

My json:

```
var cdata = [{
    "coords": [520, 360],
    "name": "2 Junior",
    "style": {"fill": "green"}
},
{
    "coords": [530, 360],
    "name": "1 Master",
    "style": {"fill": "pink"}
},
{
    "coords": [570, 330],
    "name": "1 Master",
    "style": {"fill": "pink"}
},
{
    "coords": [620, 310],
    "name": "2 Junior",
    "style": {"fill": "green"}
},
{
    "coords": [620, 325],
    "name": "1 Master",
    "style": {"fill": "pink"}
}]
```

I tried changing the order of the parameters of my map and the order of the files that the html loads without success.

Answer (score 0):

Request the `JSON` using `$.ajax()` or `$.getJSON()` instead of setting `src` of `<script>` to path to `JSON` at `<script src = "./markers.json"> </script>`, else `cdata` will not be defined, then call `.vectorMap()`

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON("./markers.json")
    .then(function(cdata) {
      $('#mex-map').vectorMap({
        map: 'Mexico',
        backgroundColor: '#b3d1ff',
        series: {
          regions: [{
            values: {
              "c0": "1",
              "c1": "2"
            },
            scale: ['#d9d4ca', '#b3d1ff'],
            normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
          }]
        },
        markerStyle: {
          initial: {
            fill: '#F8E23B',
            stroke: '#383f47',
            r: 7

          }
        },
        markers: cdata
      });
    })
    .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(errorThrown)
    })
})
```

Comment: I try with $.getJSON but not works, the problem is the same

Answer (score 0):

Can't understand why this question got two upvotes, anyway, you have a typo in your online json file:

```
{
    "coords": [360, 200],
    "name": "2 Master",
    "style": {"fill": "pink"}
},
{
    "coord": [220, 100], <---- should be coords
    "name": "2 Master",
    "style": {"fill": "pink"}
},
{
    "coords": [230, 100],
    "name": "1 Junior",
    "style": {"fill": "green"}
}
```

Comment: Are you right, i find the problem in the json the last week